# Conditional Data Insert in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables with columns:

```
A: AId, Name, Color, Path
B: BId, Name, Color, Path, PathId
C: AId, Name, Color, PathId
```

I want to check, if Table B has the Path from Table A. If the path is present, I want to get the PathId and insert it Table C. If Table B does not have the Path, I want to insert it, get the PathId and insert it in Table C. (PathId is auto incremented non nullable column)

How can I do it using SQL Server (SSMS)?
Thanks.

EDIT:
I have written the following Statements:

```
DECLARE @Temp table (
       [TempId] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
       [Name] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
       [Color] [varchar] (255) NULL,
       [PathId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)

--I want to insert values in @Temp table who have Path in TableB. 
--I am not sure how do I get the AId and the other values

MERGE Schema2.B AS B
USING Schema1.A AS A
ON B.Path= A.Path

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    INSERT Schema1.C(AId, [Name], [Color], [PathId])
    VALUES () --Stuck here (I want to add values from @Temp table)

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([Name], [Color], [Path])
VALUES (A.Tenant, A.CustomerId, A.AmsPath);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: As a starter, this query tells you _if Table B has the Path from Table A_ `SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE TableB.Path=TableA.Path)`

Comment: I have added what all things I have tried and where I am stuck. Can you please take a look

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `Values ()` with a select statement?

Comment: Yes, it says, multiple values cannot be inserted into the table.

Comment: You might need to do it without the merge statement, using 2 insert statements.

Comment: You can't use merge to insert into a different table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you want is the following where you use `NOT EXISTS` to only insert rows which don't already exist.

Also I *think* your 2 inserts can be completely separate.

Note: I'm not sure how you are generating `BId` if `PathId` is an identity column.

```
-- Add any missing records to Table B
insert into TableB (Name, Color, [Path])
select Name, Color, [Path]
from TableA ta
-- Check whether Path already exists
where not exists (
  select 1
  from TableB tb
  where tb.[Path] = ta.[Path]
);

-- Add any missing records to Table C
insert into TableC (AId, Name, Color, PathId)
select ta.AId, ta.Name, ta.Color, tb.PathId
from TableA ta
-- Join on Table B to get the PathId
join TableB tb on tb.[Path] = ta.[Path]
-- Check whether path already exists
where not exists (
  select 1
  from TableB tc
  where tc.[Path] = ta.[Path]
);
```